# How do you import a newly created ember addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm trying to create my first Ember AddOn and I'm getting stuck importing it into an Ember project. I've created the addon and published to github like this:

```
ember-cli$ ember addon test-addon
ember-cli$ cd test-addon
ember-cli/test-addon$ git remote add origin <github-url>
```

Then, from my project, I install the addon:

```
test-app$ ember install <github-url>
```

And, lastly, try to import it into a route:

```
# app/rotues/index.coffee
import TestAddon from 'test-addon'
```

But, I'm getting this error on the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `test-addon` imported from `test-app/routes/index`
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I can see the addon in the `node_modules` directory but not in `bower_components`. I think(tm) this is my issue but I'm not sure what else I need to do to setup my addon.

Comment: If you're not publishing to npm, you must [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) your addon to your ember project

Comment: Thanks @MilkyWayJoe but I don't think that's the problem. I'm publishing the addon to a private repo on github then installing it in the test-app (I added the install step to my question). I've also tried npm link as you suggested but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
cd my-addon
npm link
cd /my/project/dir
npm link my-addon
ember g my-addon  # run default blueprint
```

Then add `"my-addon": "*"` to the `devDependencies` section of your app's `package.json` and restart the ember-cli app server.

### Longer Answer

The easiest way to include a locally-developed addon is to [use NPM's `link`](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#link-to-addon-while-developing)

First run `npm link` from the root of your addon project to register it with npm. Then running `npm link <your-addon-name>` will have the same effect as `npm install`ing it.

You'll still need to manually add it to your `package.json` (required for ember-cli to find it when compiling your app) and run the [default blueprint](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#default-blueprint) (if your addon has one).

If this doesn't seem to be working, check that you've created a `package.json` in your addon with `"ember-addon"` in the `keywords` list (the default ember-cli addon blueprint should do this for you).

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because using a local repo is definitely the way to go. I forget what was wrong with importing from github but it's definitely easier to keep the addon local.

Comment: Yes, certainly for development, linking is the way to go. But if you're building somewhere else (CI or something), then I'm fairly certain you should just be to install from a private repo the same as normal... Anyway, glad you got it sorted out!